# gloabl name cx not defined

Tags: python, web.py, cx-oracle

I wanna call an Oracle function returning an objectby using cx_Oracle`s cursor.callfunc(). But this is not working

Here you can see my code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import json
import web

urls = (
"/", "index",
"/grid", "grid",
)
app = web.application(urls, globals(),web.profiler )
web.config.debug = True

connection = cx_Oracle.Connection("TEST_3D/limo1013@10.40.33.160:1521/sdetest")
typeObj = connection.gettype("MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "hallo moritz " 

class grid:

    def GET(self):
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',      '*')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')      
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.arraysize = 10000 # default = 50
        cursor.execute("""SELECT a.id AS building_nr, c.Geometry AS geometry, d.Classname FROM   building a, THEMATIC_SURFACE b, SURFACE_GEOMETRY c, OBJECTCLASS d  WHERE  a.grid_id_400 = 4158 AND a.id = b.BUILDING_ID AND b.LOD2_MULTI_SURFACE_ID = c.ROOT_ID AND c.GEOMETRY IS NOT NULL AND b.OBJECTCLASS_ID = d.ID""")

        obj = cursor.fetchone()
        obj = obj[1]
        print obj

        cursor.callfunc("SDO2GEOJSON", cx.Oracle.OBJECT, [obj])

# Aufruf der App        
if __name__ == "__main__": 
        app.run(web.profiler)
```

Error message:
 **at /grid
global name 'cx' is not defined**

But I am sure that cx_Oracle is correct installed. Furthermore I use import cx_Oracle at the beginning and this is working.

What is wrong?

Comment: You have a typo in `cursor.callfunc("SDO2GEOJSON", cx.Oracle.OBJECT, [obj])`

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo. In the line

```
cursor.callfunc("SDO2GEOJSON", cx.Oracle.OBJECT, [obj])
```

You should use `cx_Oracle.OBJECT`

Comment: ok thanks. now this error is solved. But I get another one : **cursor.callfunc("SDO2GEOJSON", cx_Oracle.OBJECT, [obj])
InterfaceError: object type not associated with bind variable**